# binned frequency from multiple variables in same column

Tags: r, dataframe, frequency

Using R, I have melted my table into two columns, variable and value. There are multiple variables and values represent lengths. I would like to end up with three columns: variable, fixed pre-determined bins and frequency of each bin per variable.

Example Data:

original table/data frame:

```
Var Value
a   509
a   1000
b   251
b   330
...
```

new table/data frame:

```
Var Bin       Count
a   0-250     50
a   251-500   30
a   501-1000  1
b   0-250     80
b   251-500   55
b   501-1000  30
...
```

Comment: take  a  look in `?cut` or `?findInterval`

Answer (score 1):

To my surprise, I haven't found a duplicate question googling the question's title.

So, here are three possible solutions using `cut()` implemented in base R, `dplyr`, and `data.table`.

```
# pre-define break points of bins
breaks <- seq(0L, 1000L, by = 250L)
```

Note that `cut()` creates left open, right closed intervals by default, e.g,
`250 < x <= 500`.
For the first interval, the parameter `include.lowest = TRUE` forces a left closed interval as well, e.g.,
`0 <= x <= 250`
which seems to be in line with OP's expected output.

#### base R

```
with(DF, table(Var, cut(Value, breaks, include.lowest = TRUE)))
```

> ```
> Var [0,250] (250,500] (500,750] (750,1e+03]
>   a       0         0         1           1
>   b       1         2         0           0
> ```

#### dpylr

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
  group_by(Var, Bin = cut(Value, breaks, include.lowest = TRUE)) %>% 
  count()
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 3
> # Groups:   Var, Bin [4]
>     Var         Bin     n
>   <chr>      <fctr> <int>
> 1     a   (500,750]     1
> 2     a (750,1e+03]     1
> 3     b     [0,250]     1
> 4     b   (250,500]     2
> ```

## data.table

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF)[, .N, by = .(Var, Bin = cut(Value, breaks, include.lowest = TRUE))]
```

> ```
>    Var         Bin N
> 1:   a   (500,750] 1
> 2:   a (750,1e+03] 1
> 3:   b     [0,250] 1
> 4:   b   (250,500] 2
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
DF <- fread("Var Value
a   509
a   1000
b   0
b   251
b   330")
```